# Installing OpenBSD 7.0 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

I'm trying to install OpenBSD 7.0 on a Raspberry Pi 4, but I'm facing some issues. This is the tutorial I'm trying to follow: https://lzomedia.com/blog/installing-openbsd-7-on-raspberry-pi-3/ (The tutorial is for the Pi 3, but the instructions are the same for the 4 as well).

I'm able to boot from USB, however once it boots to the command prompt, hitting enter gives me the error "cannot open sd0a: /etc/random.seed: No such file or directory." As a result, I can't launch the installer.

Any idea what could be the issue?

I've got miniroot.img on the SD card, and install.img on a USB drive.

Comment: OpenBSD maintains a [mailing list[(https://www.openbsd.org/mail.html). Perhaps try that first? I'm sure they'll be anxious to help as it would allow them to claim another supported platform.

Comment: As I understood, the file is always missing on a new installation, because there was no prior shutdown to create it. It is created at shutdown. It should not impact the possible launch of the installer.

Comment: @LjmDullaart Do you know what could be causing the issue? Have you faced a similar thing or can you run yours fine? I'm wondering if it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know where things go wrong at your side. Do you get a  prompt? Does `sysinstall` start? Does that give an error message? Did you put install.img on the whole drive or on the first partition?

Comment: I used dd to create the USB drive, so don't think its an issue with the USB. I get a prompt, and when I hit enter, where I'm supposed to get the installation prompt, instead it just reboots. I'm able to load the kernel tho after I hit enter. I can see the splash information on screen. But before loading the install prompt (which is what I think you're referring by sysinstall?) the system reboots.

Comment: This is clear, though I've not managed to replicate it myself:
[https://www.mtsapv.com/rpi4obsd/](https://www.mtsapv.com/rpi4obsd/)